# Spring @Transactional not working with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions, completable-future

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void test(){
    CompletableFuture cf1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(()-> dbMapper.insert());

    CompletableFuture cf2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->{
        dbMapper.insert();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    });
    CompletableFuture.allOf(cf1, cf2).join(); // this will throw CompletionException
}
```

In the above codes, I'd like to rollback the `insert()` operation in `cf1` and `cf2` when `join()` throw any exceptions. But actually no rollback happens.

how to make it works? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Transactions imply synchronous behavior.  `Future`s imply asynchronous behavior.  Real question:  why do you want to use `Future`s here at all?

Comment: @Makoto because there are a lot of db operations in the real method, which takes too much time. so I consider to execute a part of sql asynchronously.

Comment: I know this is pretty outdated question. There must be some work around on this. Could you please share your approach on this?